# How to build server streaming via grpc and nest.js?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, microservices, nestjs, grpc

Need to create some "channel" to which the client can subscribe and periodically receive messages.
Within the current technology stack, I'm trying to organize something like this:
proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package testtime;

service TimeService {    
    rpc GetTimeStream(Empty) returns (stream TimeStreamResponse);
}

message Empty {
}

message TimeStreamResponse {
    string result = 1;
}
```

controller:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const timeSubject = new Subject<{ result: string }>();
setInterval(() => {
    const result = moment().format('hh:mm');
    timeSubject.next({ result });
}, 5000);

@Controller()
export class TestTimeController {
    @GrpcMethod('testtime.TimeService', 'GetTimeStream')
    public getTimeStream(): Observable<{ result: string }> {
        return timeSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

when I try to call the method, I get an error:

```
/project/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js:141
             this.transformToObservable(await handler).subscribe(data => callback(null, data), (err) => callback(err));
                                                                         ^
 TypeError: callback is not a function
     at SafeSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js:141:73)
     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:265:10)
     at SafeSubscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:207:14)
     at Subscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:139:22)
     at Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:139:22)
     at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at TapSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/tap.ts:125:22)
     at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts:162:22)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/innerSubscribe.ts:30:17)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts:162:22)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/innerSubscribe.ts:30:17)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts:166:24)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem turned out to be that the packages from @opentelemetry patch the parsing of proto files.
Unfortunately, I do not have a right to bring a show to the problem.